Pass email id to login form | Okta external federated authentication
I am integrating Okta External Federated Authentication in the sitecore 10.2 CD and following https://github.com/kate-orlova/auth0-in-sitecore.
Okta Authentication is done. And now I want to send email id to form for autofilling. Is there a way I can do so?

For this to work, I passed the email as login_hint in processor as follows:
if (notification.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Authentication)
{
    notification.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("audience", _oktaAudience);
    string Login_hint= notification.OwinContext.Request.Query.Get("email");
    notification.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("login_hint", Login_hint);
}


